# disable controls in an amp-carousel when style=slides

Tags: html, carousel, amp-html

I'd like to hide the "previous" and "next" controls showing when the type of the amp-carousel is "slides". I have not found any documentation on how to customize the "controls" attribute.

Comment: They're here https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-carousel.html. Probably you can just `.amp-carousel-button { display: none }`

Comment: @henggana Yes you are right: adding the above code in the `<style amp-custom>` section fixes my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using css.Just add

`.amp-carousel-button { display: none }`

in amp-custom style tag

Answer (score 0):

Do this to target carousels of type slides:

```
        [type=slides] > .amp-carousel-button {
            display: none;
        }
```

This helps in case you have other carousels you want to keep their controls intact.